# raspberry pi: Can't execute script.py from PHP

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

update:

after advice in the comments I found my error.log (/var/log/apache2/error.log):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/nano.py", line 7, in <module>
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
```

I solved my problem by adding sudo:

```
<?php
echo exec("sudo /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/nano.py");
?>
```

but I still don't understand it.
I need to run it as sudo when I call nano.py from my webserver, but when I run nano.py from my terminal (as pi user) I don't have to run it as sudo.
I thought that I gave apache root access when I edited sudoers.

anyone who can explain this?
and is this safe? (my apache server is only accessible from my own wifi network for now)

---

I know this question has been asked and answered many times, but I've tried every solution I could find but I still can't execute my script.py from my PHP webpage.

I can execute my nano.py script from terminal:
[image: nano.py]

My apache server is also working fine (I can display text if I want)

nano.py script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
```

I have a python script called nano.py located at:
/var/www/html/nano.py      (-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi www-data 236 Jan 26 13:12 nano.py)
and
/home/pi/nano.py           (-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 225 Jan 26 13:19 nano.py)
the scripts are both the same:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("python /var/www/html/nano.py");
?>
```

I tried many things, but I can't execute nano.py from my PHP page:

- tried different paths(/var/www/html/nano.py /home/pi/nano.py nano.py)
- tried shell_exec, exec
- tried different python paths (python /usr/bin/python)

I tried giving apache sudo access:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I don't really know what other options I have,
So I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Check out the [Raspberry Pi SE site](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/nano.py");
?>
```

Most likely your python binary can't be found. Also make sure these functions are not blocked by your php.ini.

If that doesn't work, /var/log/apache2/error.log can tell you more about the error.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: tried that, and many other options:

    #echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/nano.py");
 #echo shell_exec("python /var/www/html/nano.py");
 #echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /home/pi/nano.py");
 #echo shell_exec("python /home/pi/nano.py");
 echo exec("/home/pi/nano.py");
?>

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat server is most likely run under the "tomcat" user account. It is probably why you need sudo command.